# Why Windows Server (2008 R2) opens text file slower than Windows Desktop (XP)

Tags: performance, text-editors, windows-server

I'm running several virtual machines (VMware workstation) on my physical PC (which is a Windows 2008 R2, Core i5 650 and 8 GB DDR3 RAM dual channel): 2x Windows Server 2008 R2 and 1x Windows XP

- 1st Windows Server has 2 CPU cores dedicated and 2 GB of RAM
- 2nd Windows Server has 1 CPU core and 1 GB of RAM
- Windows XP SP3 has 1 CPU core and 384 MB of RAM

All 3 VMs share the same physical hard drive (other than my system's hard drive)

When I open a 10-megabytes text file (which is an application log file) in notepad, it opens approximately 5-10 seconds on all 3 windows servers - my physical machine, and both virtual machines

When I open the same file on Windows XP VM -- it opens in 1-2 seconds

The question is - why Windows XP is that faster? And how to make Server OSs to open text files faster?

I am thinking the Prefetcher (which is not available on Servers) may have something to do here, could it be?

Comment: "I am thinking the Prefetcher (which is not available on Servers) may have something to do here, could it be?" - **You should verify by testing it against Windows 7. Are these Windows 2008 R2 x64 or x86. Why are you worried about the performance within a virtual machine?**

Comment: Servers are by default optimized for background processes. Windows XP is a desktop OS and therefore it prioritizes processes with windows in the foreground giving the user the fastest experience.